# Exclude symbol from capturing and get only required data?

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

I have text with days, hours, minutes, in following format:

```
4 d. 12 h. 32 m.
7 h. 22 m.
3 d. 14 h.
```

Notice, that some of them may be apsent (e.g.: `3 d. 14 h.` doesnt contains minutes)

I want to capture digit in named groups, but do not capture the characters (d. h. m.). So finally i need to get result something like this map:

```
[
    'days' => 4,
    'hours' => 12,
    'minutes' => 32,
]
```

This what i wrote: `(?P<days>(\d+) d.)?(?P<hours>(\d+) h.)?(?P<minutes>(\d+) m.)?`

Link: https://regex101.com/r/FERRnd/1

But it seems that there is some empty elements, and i have feeling that this is not best regular expression for this task. Is there any way to recieve only named params as digits and nothing else (no empty fields, no text like `12 h.` etc.)?

Many thanks!

Comment: @akond yes, this is exactly what i need! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(?:(?P<days>\d+) d.)?\s*(?:(?P<hours>\d+) h.)?\s*(?:(?P<minutes>\d+) m.)?
```

Comment: Any way to do this without matching empty string ?

Comment: It is easier to check for an empty string in a separate condition.

Answer (score 0):

akond's solution works if you are ok with matching empty string. Adding a positive lookahead at the beginning will prevent matching empty string:

```
(?=\d+\s[dhm]\.)(?:(?P<days>\d+) d.)?\s*(?:(?P<hours>\d+) h.)?\s*(?:(?P<minutes>\d+) m.)?
```